# java regular expression support lowercase characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression for Canadian zip code. But this regual expression support only upper case letters not lower case letters. Can any one please let me know how this support lower case characters.

reg exp:

`Pattern patternForZip = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z]?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$");`

How this above reg exp supports lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9][A-Za-z]?[0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]$"
```

Or can do this to make it case insensitive:

```
"(?!)^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z]?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"
```

You can try this:

```
final String regex = "^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z]?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$";
final String string = "a2a2a2\n"
        + "A2A2A2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Both regex is not working.

Comment: You haven't given any sample input and output to test the regex.. plz provide some sample input and output

Comment: input could be  "a2a 2a2" or "A2A 2A2" .Both the cases should be valid

Comment: does your original regex works for A2A 2A2 ?

Comment: i have updated the answer, it should work

Comment: Yes.It works perfectly

Comment: watch out the space between a2aSPACE2a2 I guess you don't match space... do you :) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127568/discussion-between-ravi-k-chowdary-and-maverick-mrt).

Comment: i user Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE before also, this is also not working properly

Comment: "A1A 2A2" or 'a2a 2a2' is only the example of the canadian zipcode. it could be many different zipcodes available. for reference:- http://postalcode.globefeed.com/canada_postal_code.asp?dt=udviGz~ucN&pl=Toronto,%20Ontario,%20Canada&sr=main

Comment: And i do have the same option for Javascript code :- But do not know how to embed the same in Java

Comment: Javascript :- var regex = new RegExp(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i);  This javascript regex is working perfectly for lowercase also. but the same tried to implement in java, it is throwing error.

Comment: did you put /i at the end of regex in java ? you should not

Comment: i tried to remove the first '^' as well as last character 'i' in java, still it is throwing compilation error.